# Java androidava.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader[DexPathList

Tags: java, android

I want to add in my app realm in build gradle I add a depedency but my app is crash when I want to open. When I remove a realm from build.gradle it works good, 
When I open my application my app is crash and in logcat I see this :
An aplication is crash on api 23 on api 22 is work good

```
Process: com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal, PID: 28570
                                                                                java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader[DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-25.1.1_91612f273cfd0f5d5e19936a2ad037b564182cbe-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-realm-android-0.82.1_7e76e6ffee0d1cb7e01f2c66c804c3793594de2c-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-net.zetetic-android-database-sqlcipher-3.5.4_135cd2448a0da2e86ab541f3b27f581321c1d456-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-httpmime-4.3_6e141b1d56341afe62df127e705699c8e19c8bb6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-httpcore-4.4.1_e49d006f3b2e7592fd656e18125cc2db29a10b84-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-gson-2.3.1_4a9b71ac2dc71066aa7353f2618316d6f5ee6bbb-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-commons-lang3-3.0_2b4c46e3c0bed0958adde3086cf29c2726031e84-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-commons-io-1.3.2_83725d86904b5513c36c26fcea967b3e426de013-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-transition-25.0.1_3411dc5ce9316d5957ddab54a7b8ecbe59b3dbab-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-25.0.1_05125e8df4840504b4ae843ceb84895ee6daa36e-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-25.1.1_ea8f8a08db5fc71c8eb7f0fda4dcf1514ab69445-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-media-compat-25.1.1_6e544731ad620f13576a56bc142ae24e677be5db-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-fragment-25.1.1_eb90775373924cc4dedc93cead4129f491585254-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-core-utils-25.1.1_c6608c38e296a3212b4d24448bca6ebcbf24f361-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-core-ui-25.1.1_ba7ebe69dde21969b4e93dd2b6006ddd8911438c-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-compat-25.1.1_83d6248b2e3368cd9652adb4d943c8491e05886e-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal/files/i
```

This is my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.eltegps022.smokkomunal"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime
//    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.0-alpha3'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-io
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-io', version: '1.3.2'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.0'


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.4@aar'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.3.1'
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Try installing realm in your project using the link https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#installation

Comment: @mdg5435 I do how is in this project but it doesn't work , when I create a new project it works ....